# Regarding mean centering, for subsequent linear and exponential modeling

Tags: normalization, standardization

I'm centering my age variable using R's center() function (for reference).

I am modeling the linear, quadratic, and cubic effects of age.

I am wondering if I should either:

1. Mean center Age, then ^2 and ^3 those values for their respective modeling scheme

   - (this leaves me with quadratic and cubic not centered around zero) or
2. Mean center quadratic and cubic after manipulations of 1., or
3. Take the initial age, ^2 and ^3 it, then mean center each one individually.

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One unambiguous answer was given by Aiken and West in their (now dated) book, *Multiple Regression: Testing and Interpreting Interactions*. Their strong opinion was that centering variables before taking interactions or creating polynomials was the best way to reduce 'nonessential collinearity' as well as produce a meaningful intercept. The reason for the latter statement is that introducing interactions and polynomials into a model changes the interpretation of the parameters. Main effects only model parameters are conditional on the average values of the predictors while parameters in models with interactions and polynomials are interpreted at and around zero.

Comment: So does that mean option B?

Comment: Nope...#1......